# How to fire "animationend" event, when I can't set a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, dom-events

If I set the css animation to "element", it's fine. If the Css animation is not available, how does it function fire like a zero seconds animation in the ES5?

```
function run() { ... }

element.addEventListener('animationend', run);
```

---

### Reply for

@Anurag Srivastava,

Am I wrong idea or do I have the following code wrong? Either way, the return value is "".

```js
var el1 = document.getElementById("notAnimation");

console.log(el1.style.animation);

var el2 = document.getElementById("onAnimation");

console.log(el2.style.animation);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#notAnimation {}

#onAnimation {
  animation: scale 10s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      color: black;
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(0.95);
      opacity: .4;
      color: red;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      color: black;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="notAnimation">
  Not Animation
</div>

<div id="onAnimation">
  Animation
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `element.style.WebkitAnimation` and `element.style.animation` contain any value and execute `run()` if the value is ""

**Edit** Turns out that `.style` will return "" for any value. What you need is `window.getComputedStyle()` along with the property `animationName`. If it is `none`, there is no animation, else there is. Check the code below:

```js
var el1 = document.getElementById("notAnimation");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(el1)["animationName"])

var el2 = document.getElementById("onAnimation");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(el2)["animationName"])
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#notAnimation {}

#onAnimation {
  animation: scale 10s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    opacity: .4;
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="notAnimation">
  Not Animation
</div>

<div id="onAnimation">
  Animation
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but how does this process control in the css file "element" animation value? In any case, the value "" will return.

Comment: It will return "" only if there is no animation set, else a string is returned eg. "myAnim 2s ease-in" Also, you would need to check both .animation and .WebkitAnimation

Comment: I rearranged the question and added a "code snippet" as you said. Is there something wrong with me?

Comment: thank you for your help. It's works fine now. But does this automatically detect different animation values ​​such as webkit,ms,o?

Comment: I think it does, but you must double check to be sure.